# Why do I get the message that my question does not meet the quality standards?

Tags: support

I want to ask this question:

> **Who was the author of Hebrews?**
>
> Who was the author of Hebrews, or who are the likely candidates?

But I get the message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

What am I doing wrong? What rule have I violated and how do I get the question to meet the standards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is too short. You can make it longer by adding a link to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_the_Epistle_to_the_Hebrews) wikipedia page and summarizing at least one theory mentioned there. Then you should be good.

Comment: Actually, your link kind of makes [my answer redundant](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've somehow managed to trip up the system's ["quality" filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/1438).  Exactly what you need to do to fix the question is a mystery, but you might try adding more words.

May I use this question as an example of why the system might need to give an asker a little bit of help in a question on meta.SE?

Comment: Sure! (Extra characters so I don't trip up *this* filter...)

Comment: Apparently low quality questions are a real problem on SO which could explain the stringent filtering policy across SE: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: @Wikis: If you'd like to chime in, I posted the [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118713/1438) over there.